# Stress testing making consecutive calls on a contract's entry point

Tags: smart-contracts, testing, testnet

I want to test calling the same entry point on a smart contract repeatedly. I have a smart contract that might linearly increase the gas it consumes after each consecutive call in the entry point. Of course, I would like to test it whether it is really linear.

To that, is it possible to create, for instance, 500 test wallets (on granadanet) and make many consecutive calls to some specific smart contract entry point? Can I automate that with Taquito, or any other API that might help?

Comment: As Granadanet will be dead in about 6 weeks, you should really be testing on Hangzhounet.

Comment: I will create a contract before...